# Change a range of column width repeatedly (VBA Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, column-width

I would like to change column width for a range of columns, and loop the command. For instance, change column widths for col"B" ~ col"N", then repeat the process until the last column with data. （I do not want to autofit the first column in range)

The command below however, does not work, as the column range set-up is not correct. I have tried to use Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(, colSize) but this does not work either.

```
Dim j As Integer
Dim colSize As Integer
colSize = 14

For j = 2 To Columns.Count Step colSize
Range(Columns(j), Columns(j + colSize - 1)).ColumnWidth.AutoFit
Next j
```

Thank you.

Comment: AutoFit is a method of the Range Object, not of the ColumndWidth Object. See  [AutoFit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofit). So try `Range(Columns(j), Columns(j + colSize - 1)).AutoFit`. Also, you do not need the loop - you are changing all the columns with that one statement. The loop will go through the entire sheet all the way to the right - Columns.Count = 16384, The last 14 will fail as you try to adjust widths of columns which are of the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, Autofit works without ColumnWidth! I was trying different ways and things got messed up... The reason I am looping is because I wanted to avoid autofit for the first column of every block of 14 columns. But I realized that it is easier to adjust after first autofitting the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of looping, you can simply use the `Union` method

```
     Application.Union(Columns("A:B"), Columns("D:L"), Columns("AA"), Columns("AC:AD"), Columns("AI:AJ"), Columns("AR"), Columns("AT"), Columns("BA"), Columns("BI"), Columns("BM")).Select
     Selection.ColumnWidth = 8
```

The example above comes from the worksheet, which includes sheets from A to CB or something.

You can select the columns you need (not necessarily in the correct order) and then set their width.

Comment: Thank you. I did not want to specify a specific column characters, A AA, and so forth, because the columns are long.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the width of columns for a certain range (here, 14 columns as one block, and want to autofit every 2nd col ~ 13th col in the block), the following worked. But autofit seems to take a bit of time, so rather, specifying a column width may be better.

Sub ColumnWidthChange()

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim colSize As Integer 'a block size
colSize = 14


For j = 2 To Columns.Count Step colSize
Range(Columns(j), Columns(colSize)).ColumnWidth = 11  'Range.AutoFit works but may take longer
Next j

'a space column in between blocks 
For i = colSize To Columns.Count Step colSize
Columns(i).ColumnWidth = 1
Next i

'the first column of each block
For k = 1 To Columns.Count Step colSize
Columns(k).ColumnWidth = 12
Next k
```

End Sub